# What's the most *simple* way to implement a plain data object which conforms key-value-observing?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, ios, key-value-observing

What's the most *simple* way to implement a plain data object which conforms key-value-observing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make an class with properties for its plain value attributes and [KVC-compliant collection accessors](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ModelObjects/Articles/moAccessorMethods.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002132-SW8) for collections. Foundation magic will take care of the notifications for a simple object like that.